# Component don't re render after state update

Tags: reactjs

I'm testing out react-sweet-state as an alternative to Redux, but I feel like I'm missing something.

This is how my store is written :

```
import { createStore, createHook } from 'react-sweet-state'

const initialState = {
    startHolidayButton: true,
}

const actions = {
    setStartHolidayButton: value => ({ setState }) => {
        setState({ startHolidayButton: value })
    },
}

const ButtonsVisibleStore = createStore({
    initialState,
    actions,
    name: 'ButtonsVisibleStore',
})

export const useButtonsVisible = createHook(ButtonsVisibleStore)
```

In my eyes it all seems pretty fine, the hooks works as long as I only need the initial state.
This is how I access and modify it :

```
const App = () => {
    const [state, actions] = useButtonsVisible()
    return (
        <Styled>
            <MainMenu />
            <div className="l-opacity">
                <WorldMap />
            </div>

            {state.startHolidayButton && (
                <div
                    className="bottom-toolbar"
                    onClick={() => {
                        actions.setStartHolidayButton(false)
                    }}>
                    <StartSelectionButton />
                </div>
            )}
        </Styled>
    )
}
```

I can read the values from the `state` and I can trigger the `actions` but if an action updates a state value, my component don't re render, it's like he is unaware that something has been updated.

So am I doing it the right way or are actions not meant for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, actions] = useButtonsVisible();
  return (
    <div className="App">
  {state.startHolidayButton ?
    (
      <div
        className="bottom-toolbar"
        onClick={() => {
          actions.setStartHolidayButton(false);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </div>
    )
    :
    (
        <div
          className="bottom-toolbar green"
          onClick={() => {
            actions.setStartHolidayButton(true);
          }}
        >
          click me
        </div>
    )
  }
</div>
);
}
```

With some changes your code works fine. Here is the css: .bottom-toolbar {   display: inline-block;   width: 100%;   height: 50px;   background: red;   cursor: pointer; } .bottom-toolbar.green {   background: green; }

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mendeleev-o9zv7?file=/src/styles.css:58-218